# $\text{Solution of Wave equation }$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

$\text{Solution The  equation }$

$U_{tt}=4U_{xx}-U_t, 0<x<3,t>0\\
U(0,t)=U(3,t)=0,t>0\\
U(x,0)=e^x,U_t(x,0)=0,0<x<3$

when we use variable and separable U(x,t)=X(x)T(t)
i get solutions for the $X_n(x)$ but i have faced problem with finding $T_n(t)$ can any one please help me with this part

Comment: It's a version of the _Telegraphers_ equation. It's linear and on a bounded domain, so use separation of variables.

Comment: **Please** do **not** do that to titles.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez..sorry

Comment: @Mattos..i have faced problem with solving T(t) by using varible and separable